How to write.table a RowReordered table
I am trying to give the user the option to look at a subset of a data table, reorder that subset with RowReorders drag and drop function, then then export that now reordered data to a file.
I have the subset view and the drag and drop working and I know how to write.table, my issue is that write table works on a data frame and not on my rendered table im allowing my user to reorder.
How do I print my reordered table?
Here is my RowReorder code if it helps:
output$dtable <- renderDT(server=FALSE,{ datatable( downloadsubset(),  colnames=c(ID = 1), extensions ='RowReorder',options=list( order=list(list(0,'asc')), rowReorder=TRUE, iDisplayLength=25,  columnDefs=list(list(className="nowrap", targets="_all" ) )))})


and my download code:
#what happenes when you press the download button
                                             output$download_file <- downloadHandler(
                                               #set the file name, here it is "Download" then the date then .txt
                                               filename = function() { paste0("Download", gsub(":", "-", Sys.time()),".txt")},
                                               #set what will be downloaded, here it is the data from the reactive value downloadsubset
                                               content = function(file) { write.table(downloadsubset(),file, row.names = FALSE, na="", sep="\t", quote=FALSE) }
                                        
                                             )

I have tried passing the table itself to write.table but that did not work. Is there a way to capture the data in the rendered table, save it to a new data.table, and then export THAT?
I need the data from the reordered table which the user is manipulating to be able to be exported.
Thanks!


Greg Deiulio No feedback regarding my answer?..


This is not very easy.
The main part of the code is taken from this blog post.
One has to listen to the JavaScript event row-reorder to keep track of the changes performed by the row reorderings.
In the code below I use write.csv but of course you can use write.table instead.
library(shiny)
library(DT)


dat <- data.frame(
  Type  = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  Value = c(100, 90, 80, 70)
)

rowsIndices <- 0:(nrow(dat)-1)

js <- c(
  "table.on('row-reorder', function(e, details, edit) {",
  sprintf("  var order = [%s];", toString(rowsIndices)),
  "  for(entry of details) {",
  "    order[entry.newPosition] = entry.oldPosition;",
  "  }",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('newOrder', order);",
  "});"
)

showRowNames <- TRUE # whether to show the row names


ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  downloadButton("dwnlbutton", label = "Download"),
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)


server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$dtable <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat,
      rownames = showRowNames,
      extensions = "RowReorder",
      callback = JS(js),
      options = list(rowReorder = TRUE)
    )
  }, server = TRUE)
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("dtable")
  
  Dat <- reactiveVal(dat) # we will keep track of the row reorderings in this reactive dataset
  
  observeEvent(input$newOrder, {
    dat0 <- Dat()
    dat1 <- dat0[input$newOrder + 1, ]
    replaceData(proxy, dat1, resetPaging = FALSE, rownames = showRowNames)
    Dat(dat1)
  })

  output$dwnlbutton <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0("mydata-", Sys.Date(), ".csv")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(Dat(), file)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

